# llvm/ExecutionEngine/JITSymbol.h not found

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

I compiled the llvm3.9.1 from the [source](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html#3.9.1). After I install it. I check the /usr/local/include file, and find the llvm/ExecutionEngine/JITSymbol.h is missing, instead JITSymbolFlags.h is there.

[image]

I also download the older version llvm3.9.0 and llvm3.8.1. The JITSymbol.h is still missing. But when I google this. I find the head file in the [llvm](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm) github mirror.

It makes me confused. Why?

Comment: That header must have been created more recently. You can see that if you switch to the `release_39` branch on github, it's not there.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I found it on the release_40 branch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My llvm version is 3.8, I found "JITSymbol.h" no more in ExecutionEngine directory, but in llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc directory.